# Swift 3 iOS HTTP Post

Tags: ios, swift

This code gathers the data just fine, but the post is supposed to filter some data. I made an Android and Windows Universal app which all do the same thing, but I'm almost done with my iOS app, and I ran in to a wall here. What's wrong with my post code? I just want to post something and get the data returned async.

```
let geturl = URL(string: "http://myweb.com")!
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.showActivityIndicator(uiView: realMainTable4)

        var request = URLRequest(url: geturl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "filter=on"
        request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if data != nil {
                let ret2 = String(data:data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

                var myData = [String]()
                myData = self.matches(num: 0, for: self.containerRegex, in: ret2)
                for p in myData {
                    browseTitles.append(self.match(num: 1, for: self.titleRegex, in: p))
                    browseThumbs.append(self.match(num: 1, for: self.thumbRegex, in: p))
                    browseIDs.append(self.match(num: 1, for: self.idRegex, in: p))
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.realMainTable4.reloadData()
                    appDelegate.hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.realMainTable4)
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
```

Comment: This looks basically OK. Have you looked at `ret2`? Does it have what you expected? If not, have you looked at `error` object to see what's wrong? Have you configured your plist to allow `http` requests (`URLSession`, by default, expects `https` because `http` is so insecure)?

Comment: @Rob yes I configured my plist to allow http requests. ret2 returns the unfiltered data.

Comment: @Rob It's just not sending the post data. Is there any way I can see if it's sending a post method or get method, and what post data it's sending just to verify the data is going over correctly?

Comment: In answer to your question, you can also use [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) to see the raw request and responses. But before you go installing third party software, just see what this `ret2` variable contained. Don't get lost in this software. Look at what `URLSession` provided, first.

Comment: BTW, the one thing missing from your POST is the setting of the `Content-Type` header: `request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`. It's not always required, but at worst it's good practice, and sometimes it's needed if your service accepts multiple content-types.

Comment: @Rob Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000023d140> { URL: http://mystuff.com } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = none;
    "CF-RAY" = "2faa61d305a9529c-MIA";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 31 Oct 2016 22:00:53 GMT";
    Server = "mystuff";
    "Set-Cookie" = "cookiestuff";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} })]

Comment: A server response of 200 is good. That means that there were no fundamental server errors. And `ret2` is what you expected it to be? And `error` is `nil`?

Comment: @Rob error is nil. ret2 is just not filtered. Is there any way in XCode I can see what data I'm sending? Like what method it's using and what data it's sending?

Comment: @Rob if you want I can show you what works in Java or C#.

Comment: You can use Charles or Wireshark to look at what's sent. I use these tools (I use Charles) when creating really complicated requests, but your request is so trivial (`filter=on`), I'm not sure how illuminating that will be. But run one of these tools, and do your C# request and then do your Swift request, and you can compare and contrast. Are you sure that `filter=on` is precisely what you sent in your Java or C# examples?

Comment: @Rob Thank you. I opened Wireshark and the Andriod app on my Windows PC. Then opened Wireshark and the iOS app on my Mac laptop. I compared the information back n forth until finally I noticed a very small difference. I was posting data to `http://www.` on my Andriod app and on my iOS app I was posting to `http://` Once I changed it to `http://www.myweb.com` it worked 0_0